# syntax error missing expression

Tags: sql

Hi i'm trying to show the name of all Customers who have only one account with a balance of more than $1000 in any branch of the bank and one or more loan with an amount of more than $4000 in any branch in Edina

```
select account.cname, 
from Account
where account.bal > 1000
UNION
(select loan.cname
 from loan
 where loan.amt>4000 AND
    l.bname )in (
        select bname
        from branch
        where lower(bcity)= 'edina'
    );
```

does it look right?

Comment: Why parentheses around second select?

Comment: What is the **exact** error message?

Comment: You have a comma in the first line.

Comment: Debugging is part of programmer's job.  It's very obvious where the errors are.  First line you have `,`.  Remove the `,`.  Somewhere in the middle `l.bname )in (`.  Remove the `)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra comma in first select.
your in clause doe not have a column to compare with

Maybe something like:

```
select account.cname
from Account 
where account.bal > 1000 
UNION 
select loan.cname 
from loan 
where loan.amt>4000 AND l.bname 
and loan.bname in ( select bname from branch where lower(bcity)= 'edina' )
```